# Use javascript data in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

i'm new in web programing and i have a problem with using javascript (jquery) in Cakephp . 
Indeed, I'm using a pop up (dialog) in jquery and depending on what the user click on the result  has to be register in the database so i think i have to give the result to the controller. 
I don't know how to pass a value from the view to the controller without using a form. 
For example, when the user click on the button "yes" in the dialog I want to register this data.
I put my code below , thank you.

```
//view.ctp
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Oui": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Non": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation de paiement">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Avez vous effectué le paiement ? </p>
</div>
```

Comment: had you tried it to do with `ajax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event is happening on the client side (javascript), you'll need to POST your data to a controller method via AJAX (also convenient since you are already using jQuery).

#### JS code

```
$(function() {

  // yes = 1, no = 0
  function recordClick(val) {
    console.log('sending...');

    // return ajax call, which returns a Promise object
    return  $.ajax({
      url: 'controller/method',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {the_value: val},
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Data was sent!');
      }
    });
  }

  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

      "Oui": function() {
        recordClick(1).then(function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        });
      },

      "Non": function() {
        recordClick(0).then(function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

#### Cake 2.x code

```php
<?php

public function method() {
  // Run only if this is an AJAX request and we are POSTing data
  if ($this->request->is('ajax') && !empty($this->request->data)) {
    $value_to_save = $this->request->data['the_value'];

    if ($value_to_save == 1) {
      $this->Controller->save('yes');
    } else {
      $this->Controller->save('no');
    }
  } else {
    throw new \MethodNotAllowedException('This method is not allowed');
  }
}
```

Without seeing your controller methods and everything its difficult, but that is more or less what you'd want.

---

So from a high perspective:

1. On button click from within the modal, call a JS function, passing in a parameter based on what you clicked ('1' for Yes, '0' for No).
2. That function makes an AJAX request to some controller method, and passes in the data is received from its argument into the `data` attribute of the AJAX call.
3. Your controller method will access that data via `$this->request->data`, in this case, we passed it as `the_value`.
4. From within your controller method, after you have the data, save it to your database using whatever means you normally do.

Comment: Sorry, finally it hasn't work , indeed the ajax request doesn't work. For the URL which folder should i choose knowing that the view.ctp is connected to the AccountsController folder view() function. I put as URL : AccountsController.php link it might be the problem, thank you for your help

Comment: Otherwise the problem come from the recordClick function because i can't close my popup recordClick(1).then(function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        });                                                                                                       , thank you for your help